# Target dynamic value with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have code that is working except I cannot figure out how to target the value that is generated dynamically by php.

So basically when the user clicks on the hour fields to insert hours on Monday through Sunday, both divs will appear. I tried targeting the #hours class that surrounds the fields but does not work.

```
$(function () {
   //hide hours on phone graphic and display when clicked
   $(".hours_bg").hide();
   $(".hours").keyup(function() {
   $("#hours_bg").show(); 
});
```

Also, here is an example targeting an id that works, but again I have no form id, values are creating dynamically by php.

http://jsfiddle.net/1uu1uc7c/3/

update: Here is the view where the php variables are passed dynamically. http://laravel.io/bin/zz8Pr

Comment: don't use id `hours_bg` for multiple elements, use class instead.

Comment: is `hours` getting created dynamically and every `hours` will have `hours_bg` element inside it?

Comment: add class to your form and target it

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but you might want to use `$(this)` in your event call to target the element that triggered it.

Comment: where is the markup thats created by PHP?

Comment: Show your HTML output that is generated by PHP.

Comment: Here is the view where the php variables are passed dynamically. http://laravel.io/bin/zz8Pr

Comment: The above code contains an error, you've closed one `function` instead of two. If that is real code, that should not work. Furthermore, in none of your examples I can find the elements with the `hours` or `hours_bg` classes or `hours_bg` id.